# Close opencart minicart by a second click on the dropdown arrow

Tags: opencart

This is the original code to open the opencart minicart with the dopdown arrow

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
    $('#cart').addClass('active');
    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeAttr('class');
    });
});
```

To close it on desktop screens I only have to leave the dropdown container with the mouse but it doesn't work with a mobile device like iPad or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
    if($('#cart').hasClass('active') {
        $('#cart').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#cart').addClass('active');
    }

    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeAttr('class');
    });
});
```

In shorter version this should also work, but I never found the `toggleClass` function to work for me, therefore I am toggling manually by `if-else` as above.

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
    $('#cart').toggleClass('active');

    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeAttr('class');
    });
});
```